# Get next 3rd month name from the current month in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, monthcalendar

How can I get The 3rd month names from Current month to Nov. Ex:-if the current month is Nov then I want the month names from Feb. Current month should be the running month.

**Question:** How to get 3rd month name from the current month?

Can someone please explain to me how to get month name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do it with Calendar, show your code of how you tried to do it.

Comment: 3 months from November should be February

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Calendar class, e.g.

```
var now = Date()
var calendar = Calendar.current


if let then = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 3, to: now) {
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
  let monthName = dateFormatter.string(from: then)
  print ("\(monthName)")
}
```

Just keep in mind how calenar arithmetics is handled: if you add "3 months" to let's say Nov **30th**, 2019, then you'll get Feb-**29th**, 2020, although someone might expect March-01, 2020.

Answer (score 1):

```
//set start & end date in correct format
let startDate = "September"
let strEndDate = "December"

//create date formatter
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"

//convert string into date object
guard let startDate = formatter.date(from: startDate) else {
  print("invalid start date")
   return
}

 //convert string into date object
guard let endDate = formatter.date(from: strEndDate) else {
  print("invalid end date time")
  return
}

//calculate the month from end date and that should not exceed the start date
for month in 1...6 {

  if let dt = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -month, to: endDate) {
     if dt.compare(startDate) == .orderedAscending {
        break
      } 
      print(formatter.string(from: dt!))
  }
}
```